# How to prove or disprove $ |r'(a)| \leq c_1 \sup_{x \in [a-1/2,a+1/2]} |r(x)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, rational-functions

Let matrix $ A  = \begin{bmatrix}
  a & 1 \\ 0 & a
 \end{bmatrix}$ is a Jordan matrix with $ -1 < a < 1 $.

Let $ r(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)} $ is any an irreducible rational function, where $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ are polynomials of degree $k$ with **real coefficients**, and $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ are not zero on the interval $E = \{v^\top Av | v \in \mathbb{R}^2, \|v\| = 1\} = [a-1/2, a+1/2]$.

**My problem is finding a positive number $c$ (possibly depends on $k$) such that
\begin{equation}\notag
  \|r(A)\|_2 \leq c \sup_{x \in E} |r(x)|.
\end{equation}**

Now I have get that
\begin{equation}\notag
  r(A) = \begin{bmatrix}
   r(a) & r'(a) \\ 0 & r(a)
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and $\|r(A)\|_2 \leq \sqrt{2}\|r(A)\|_1 = \sqrt{2}(|r(a)| + |r'(a)|)$. Thus **I guess that there may exist a positive number $c_1$ (possibly depends on $k$) such that
\begin{equation}\notag
  |r'(a)|  \leq c_1 \sup_{x \in E} |r(x)|.
\end{equation}**
However, I don't know how to prove or disprove this conjecture.

Comment: Since $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials that are not zero in $[-1,1]$ you can find the maximum of their ratio on $E$. Use the norm $\sup$ norm.

Comment: For polynomials this is a famous result of Bernstein with $c_1=k^2$ in general and something like $9k$ for the case of no zeroes in $[-1,1]$

Comment: @MrProof Thanks for your tip. $r'/r = p'/p - q'/q$, this latter expression is easier to handle.

Comment: @Conrad Thank you very much for your pointers, I have found [this paper](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/acta/2017/0219/0001/ACTA-2017-0219-0001-a003.pdf) with a famous result of Bernstein.

Comment: [This paper ''The numerical range as a spectral set''](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.00668.pdf) gives a result that if $W(A) \subset F$, then $\|r(A)\|_2 \leq (1+\sqrt{2}) \sup_{x \in F} |r(x)|$, where $W(A) := \{v^*Av | v \in \mathbb{C}^2, \|v\| = 1\}$ is numerical range of $A$. I'm not sure there is a similar conclusion for this question above $\|r(A)\|_2 \leq c \sup_{x \in E} |r(x)|$, where $E =  \{v^\top Av | v \in \mathbb{R}^2, \|v\| = 1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k>0.$ Let $1>d>0.$ Let $q(x)=(x+1+d)^k.$ Let $p(x)=1+q(x).$ Then $r(x)=1+(x+1+d)^{-k}$ and $r'(x)=-k(x+1+d)^{-k-1}.$ So on $[-1,1]$ we have $$\frac {\sup |r'|}{\sup |r|}=\frac {kd^{-k-1}}{1+d^{-k}}=\frac {kd^{-1}}{d^k+1}>\frac {kd^{-1}}{2}$$ which can be arbitrarily large if $d$ is close enough to $0.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it has inspired me a lot.

Comment: I now feel that E should not be $[-1,1]$, but should be $\{v^\top A v | \|v\| = 1, v \in \mathbb{R}^2 \} = [a-1/2, a+ 1/2]$, and the $|r'(a)| \leq sup_{x \in E} |r'(x)| \leq c_1 sup_{x \in E} |r(x)| $ in the conjecture should be changed to $|r'(a)| \leq c_1 sup_{x \in E} |r(x)| $.